How can I find out the location of an Azure external table?
I managed to store a PySpark data frame as a parquet file in a location controlled by me.
df.write.parquet('abfss://mycontainer@mylocation/Test')

and I created an external table in synapse with that parquet file. I could build a synapse pipeline and automate these two steps but, is there a simpler way to do it all at once in the same Jupyter notebook? Just a command that creates the external table in a given database with the content of that parquet file?
Thanks very much in avance.

You can use the Spark SQL capabilities to create an external table that points to your Parquet file.
# Assuming you've already written the Parquet file
df.write.parquet('abfss://mycontainer@mylocation/Test')

# Now, create the external table
table_name = "your_table_name"
database_name = "your_database_name"
location = "abfss://mycontainer@mylocation/Test"

# Create the external table
spark.sql(f"""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {database_name}.{table_name}
USING PARQUET
LOCATION '{location}'
""")

# Optionally, you can refresh the table to ensure the latest data is visible
spark.sql(f"REFRESH TABLE {database_name}.{table_name}")

The schema of the external table will be inferred from the Parquet files. If you need more control over the schema, you can explicitly define it in the CREATE TABLE statement.
